# Equivalence Relation - $\forall f,g \in W : fLg \iff \lim_{x \to {\infty}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to {\infty}}g(x)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is $W=\left\{ f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R | \lim_{x \to \infty} exists\right\}$

Equivalence relation L :

$\forall f,g \in W : fLg \iff \lim_{x \to {\infty}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to {\infty}}g(x)$

$1.$ Prove every relation class has the same cardinality and what it is.

$2.$ Find cardinality $W/L$

My solution:

$1.$ I know that for every real number a there exists a sequence $r_n$ of rational numbers such that $r_n$ approaches a.
I dont know how to deal with it from here.

$2.$ There are $\mathfrak{c}$ real numbers so $|W/L|=\mathfrak{c}$

I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: are the functions continuous?

Comment: Its not specified.

Comment: ok two hints: first every equivalence class must have the same cardinality since if $(x_n)\rightarrow a$ then $(x_n+a)\rightarrow b+a$ (this will help you find a bijection between equivalence classes) then notice the correspondece between an equivalence class an the limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $|\{f : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}\}| = |\mathbb{R}|^{|(0, \infty)|} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{2^{\aleph_0}} = 2^{\aleph_0 \times 2^{\aleph_0}} = 2^{\max(\aleph_0, 2^{\aleph_0})} = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}} = \beth_2$. This provides an upper bound on the cardinality of an equivalence class.

Secondly, consider the equivalence class which converges to a fixed number $c$ - call this class $C$. Consider the following function $g : \{f : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}\} \to C$ defined by

$$g(f)(x) = \begin{cases}
  f(x) & x \in (0, 1) \\
  c    & otherwise
\end{cases}$$

Clearly, $g$ is injective. Thus, $|C| \geq |\{f : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}\}| = \beth_2$.

Thus, $|C| = \beth_2 = 2^{\frak c}$, where ${\frak c} = 2^{\aleph_0} = |\mathbb{R}|$.

Your solution for part 2 is correct.

Comment: Thank you ! but$ |C| \geq |\{f : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}\}| \geq \frak c^2 = \frak c$ , no ?

Comment: @erez I mean, it is technically true that $|C| \geq {\frak c}^2$. It's just not relevant. $|\{f : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}\}| = |\{f : (0, \infty \to \mathbb{R}\}| = \beth_2$.